# Why does this sub query fail?

Tags: sql-server

I have a fairly complex query that works fine in Access and MySQL, but is not working in MS SQL.  Receive a message that "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'ORDER'".  The goal of the query is to get the top 100 orders, with expedited shipping ('USPS Express') first.

```
SELECT * 
FROM    (   SELECT 
            TOP 100     o.orderid
                    ,   (   
                            select 1 
                            from    orders 
                            where   orderid = o.orderid 
                            and     oshipmethod = 'USPS Express'
                        ) as ship_priority 
            FROM    orders o 
            WHERE   o.order_status = 10 
        ) 
ORDER BY ship_priority DESC
```

Any obvious reason why this query fails?

Comment: The inner TOP doesn't have a corresponding ORDER BY clause. Exactly which TOP 100 rows do you expect?

Comment: I'm not sure why people think the version of SQL Server they're using should be such a well-guarded secret. It is often a crucial part of the solution.

Comment: Good catch Arron, I moved the TOP 100 to the outer select where it belongs

Answer (score 3):

You have to provide an alias to the derived table output / sub query output. Otherwise, you will encounter an error.

Having said that, I believe that this query can be written in a much better way.

*Correct version*: Notice **T1** before the `ORDER BY` clause. I gave a simple name but you can name it however you would like to. Instead of T1, meaningful name would be advisable.

```
SELECT * 
FROM    (   SELECT 
            TOP 100     o.orderid
                    ,   (   
                            select 1 
                            from    orders 
                            where   orderid = o.orderid 
                            and     oshipmethod = 'USPS Express'
                        ) as ship_priority 
            FROM    orders o 
            WHERE   o.order_status = 10 
        )  T1
ORDER BY ship_priority DESC
```

Comment: Excellent, adding the derived table name worked perfectly, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You're missing the alias of the outer derived table:

Change this:

```
        WHERE   o.order_status = 10 
    ) 
ORDER BY ship_priority DESC
```

Into this:

```
        WHERE   o.order_status = 10 
    ) as derivedTable
ORDER BY ship_priority DESC
```